# SAP Cloud SDK JS receives empty data from Enterprise Messaging Queue

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

I have build a simple `cloud-SDK` based application for adding as a `Webhook` in `Enterprise messaging queue` to receive the events as soon as it gets inside the queue.

I have an `OPTIONS` and `POST` function. `OPTIONS` is for the handshake with the queue and it works.

Now, when there is message in the Queue, it hits my application with the `POST` block but the `request body` is coming as empty object.

I have tried the same from the `postman`, I'm able to receive the data in `request body`. Only from the `Enterprise messaging queue`, the data is empty.

In contrast, to verify this, I have used a `Express` based `nodejs` application, there I'm able to receive the data from the queue.

What am I missing in the Cloud-SDK based code ?

POST block, looks like this

```
  @Post('ems-events')
  receiveEmsEvents(@Body() requestBody: string, @Req() req:Request) {
     Logger.log("Event Received with Data:");
     Logger.log(requestBody);
     Logger.log(req.body);
     Logger.log("Log over--");
     Logger.log(Object.keys(req));

    return {};
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The SAP Cloud SDK for JavaScript does not offer any support for Enterprise Messaging as of today. The code you're writing here is most likely [Nest.js](https://nestjs.com/) code, which is an independent framework. 
That being said, Nest.js does run Express.js under the hood by default. So if you've been able to make it work in Express, you should be able to make it work in Nest.

Comment: What could be the problem in Nest.js. why only from EMQ body is empty. is there any other way to receive the data other than @-Body and @-Req ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the protocol is that Enterprise Messaging is using. If it's HTTP, it should work, otherwise I don't know... Can you share the code that you've written for Express that worked?